# Equality question solution

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
[image]

> I understand how they evaluated the value of x but confuses that why  they reject the solution $\frac{-3}{5}$!!!

Comment: $|x+3|$ is a non-negative number, but when $x=-\frac{3}{5}$ the RHS is negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, test it. Let $x = -3/5$. Then

$$|x+3| = |-3/5+3| = |12/5| = 12/5 \color{red}{\ne} -12/5 = 4x.$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, $x$ must be greater or equal to 0, because $4x$ is a module of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $|x + 3| = 4x$, this implies that $4x$ must be nonnegative (since $|x + 3|$ is clearly nonnegative).

Therefore, $x = -\frac{3}{5}$ is not a solution since $4x$ would then be $-\frac{12}{5}$ and thus negative.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value is always non negative. If $x=\frac{-3}{5}$ you would get $0\leq |\frac{-3}{5}+3|=-\frac{12}{5}$ and this is impossible.